# rails3 custom validation overlapping dates error

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, date-range

Building a validator that has to check multiple siblings who belong to the same (option) parent.

```
class Optionrate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :option

  attr_accessible :from, :to, :option_id

  validates_presence_of :from, :to

  validate :not_overlap

  scope :overlaps, ->(from, to) do
    where "((from <= ?) and (to >= ?))", to, from
  end

  def overlaps?
    overlaps.exists?
  end

  def overlaps
    siblings.overlaps from, to
  end

  def not_overlap
    errors.add(:key, t('overlap_message')) if overlaps?
  end

  def siblings
    Optionrate.where('option_id = ?', option_id).all
  end
```

is generating an error: "undefined method `overlaps' for []:Array"  referring to statement

```
siblings.overlaps from, to
```

The fact that siblings is plural makes me assume it is expecting an array, so that's an oddity.

[Another was that the where statement was not accepting ***where('option_id = ?', params[:option_id])*** whence the record has yet to be created as the validation has not completed]

Comment: remove `.all` in `siblings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to run the code after removing `.all` from `Optionrate.where('option_id = ?', option_id).all` because when you are using `.Where` then there is no need to use `.all` method.

Or

Take a look on following url for reference
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_2_release_notes.html#active-record

Comment: Yes, you and phoet hit the issue on its head. Now, the translations key cannot take the i18n helper method t().  Only 'overlap_message' runs.  Digging through that one!

Comment: try this `errors.add(:key, I18n.t :overlap_message) if overlaps?` i hope you have **overlap_message** key in translation files.